# Does conservation of charge has anything to do with phase?

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, conservation-laws

I was watching [youtube lecture link](https://youtu.be/i9WixHfiZPU?t=1581) and professor says that "the independence of that phase leads to conservation of charge" in the following equation.

$$\vec{\nabla} \cdot \vec{J} + \frac{\partial \rho}{\partial t}=0 .$$

What does phase has to do with charge conservation? I have tried to look for further resources but I am going nowhere.

Comment: Which phase are you talking about? If you're talking about the phase of the electromagnetic field, yes it's possible to give meaning to that. Conservation of charge is related to a symmetry group called $U(1)$, which is related to a phase.

Comment: Can you please clarify ..I honestly don't know anything about symmetry group or how it is related to charge conservation/

Comment: It's a result that comes that quantum theory. Are you familiar with it? Otherwise, it might be a result that you'll keep at the back of your mind until you learn more physics.

Comment: That's unfortunate , I am only familiar with quantum mechanics basics ( 8.04 mitocw level), are there any resources that could shed more light to it ?

Comment: A quick search here yields [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/72022/show-that-charge-conservation-partial-mu-j-mu-0-implies-global-u1-invar). It isn't the whole story but it's a start.